# Bundle install cause strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm getting a strange error message when running `bundle install` or even just `rails -v` within a rails project root directory:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 16 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

However this doesn't happen in my home directory `/Users/myname`

I messed up something and don't know what, any help?

**EDIT**
Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'checkr-official'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'linkedin'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'RedCloth'
gem "refile", require: "refile/rails"
gem "refile-mini_magick"
gem 'StreetAddress'
gem "stripe"
gem 'truevault', github: "marks/truevault.rb", ref: "e3bda1af6bfb355"
gem 'whenever', '~> 0.9.4'
gem 'impressionist'
gem "koala"
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.11.1'
# CSS and javascript
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'ejs'
gem 'faker'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.8.1'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Generic admin requirements not specified elsewhere
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 3.3' # 3.3 adds better support for media css object
gem 'simple_form', ">= 3.1.0.rc2"
# google api client used for dashboard authorization for google analytics
gem 'google-api-client'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem "capistrano-db-tasks", require: false

group :development do
  gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"

  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '1.4.0'
end
```

Comment: Share your `Gemfile` please.

Comment: try removing your Gemfile.lock file and run bundle install.

Comment: According to your `Gemfile` the ruby version should be `2.2.0` but your local version is `2.0`, install `2.2.0` and run bundle install again.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably caused by a corruption of the Rails installation.

Try running `gem list`. If you don't see `railties` in the list, run `gem install rails`.

If that doesn't work, I think you should try starting afresh. Create a new gemset, install bundler and run `bundle install`. That should fix things.

Comment: ok I ran`gem list` and don't see `railties`. Trying your solution now.